# Python 3 Pandas - Column with extra \n\t\t\t\t\t

Tags: python, excel, python-3.x, pandas

I have a dataframe from a .xls spreadsheet and I print off the columns `print(df.columns.values)` and the output contains a column with the name: `Poll Responses\n\t\t\t\t\t`.

I look in the excel sheet and in the cell column header, there's no additional spaces or tabs.

So in order to get the data from those columns, I have to use `print(df['Poll Responses\n\t\t\t\t\t'])`

Is this is how it is, or am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `.str.strip`:

```
df.columns = df.columns.str.strip()
```

This will strip whitespace from column headings in dataframe.